# C# Короткая запись метода с помощью анонимного делегата

Tags: c#, делегаты

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать 
Вот исходный код

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', v => Inc(v));
private static void Inc(IVirtualMachine v)
{
    if (v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] == (char)255)
        v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] = (char)0;
    else
        v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer]++;
}
```

Хочу заменить на что то вроде

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', b => (b.Memory[b.MemoryPointer] == 255) ? 1 : 2 );
```

на 1:2 не обращайте внимания это для сокращения кода

Comment: в чем проблема с заменой?

Comment: IVirtualMachine.Memory это масив byte

Comment: ну и что? Это что-то меняет?

Comment: А почему вы пишете в него `char`?

Comment: Мне компилятор выдает что в качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания,вызова, и тд и тп.

Comment: Вот и хотел узнать как правильно всё оформить

Comment: Почему вы записываете в byte-массив значение типа char? Это же не скомпилируется

Comment: код в верху и просто пример, чтоб была понятно логика,типы я конечно же привожу так как надо,мне больше интересен способ оформления делегата

Comment: Ну смотрите мой ответ тогда. Но если там реально `byte`-массив, то код можно еще сократить

Comment: У вас вот тут проблема `(b.Memory[b.MemoryPointer] == 255) ? 1 : 2`. Это проверка на условие с последующим присваиванием, а ничему выражение не присваивается. Как уже поправили в ответе: достаточно перед выражением поставить переменную, которой нужно присваивать значения 1 или 2

Comment: спасибо что объяснили) оказалось все очень просто)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну у вас по сути сложение по модулю, поэтому можно записать вместо `if` что-то вроде `v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] = (char)((v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] + 1) % 256)`, ну и, соответственно, в виде лямбды:

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', v =>
    v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] = (char)((v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] + 1) % 256));
```

Если `IVirtualMachine.Memory` – это реально `byte`-массив, то код можно сократить:

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', v => v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer]++));
```

Если вы хотите переписать свой метод дословно, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', v =>
{
    if (v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] == (char)255)
        v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] = (char)0;
    else
        v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer]++;
});
```

Но это не улучшает читаемость, а даже скорее наоборот.

А с использованием тернарного оператора, например, так:

```
vm.RegisterCommand('+', v =>
    v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] = (char)(v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] == 255
                                       ? 0
                                       : (v.Memory[v.MemoryPointer] + 1)
                                      ));
```

Comment: спасибо, даже не думал об этом способе, получается что в лямбде нельзя использовать сравнение и оператор "?" ?

Comment: Можно, но в данном случае это не нужно.

Comment: а можете привести пример? т.к. дальше планирую использовать эту конструкцию

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться)